# ASP.NET Core ajax and Async C# methods

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, asp.net-core

Probably one big dumb question for many, but ajax is already async, so is there any point in making for example, a method that returns me some data from database async?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using async, two or more operations are running in different contexts (thread) so that they can run concurrently and do not block each other. :)

Comment: I see so if i send an ajax request, one thread will be fetching data and the other will be doing something else on the background while page is not refreshed